# How to use Nlog tempdir directory and file name

Tags: c#, nlog

I'm trying to use Nlog to log to file in the temporary directory.

In the configuration file I have the following for the File target.

```
fileName="${tempdir:folder=myapptmp}/sample.log"
```

No file gets generated, how do I set it correctly ?

Comment: I am not familiar with the syntax you are trying to use here, but I'm not sure if you are going to be able to achieve what you want to do.

  [According to this thread you cannot use VS wildcards in .config files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903621/can-you-use-vs-macros-in-config-files)

In the debugger what is the value for fileName if you try to store it in a string variable?

Comment: Try fileName="${tempdir:dir=myapptmp:file=sample.log}"

Comment: John you are correct, can you make your suggestion an answer

Answer (score 1):

You missed this two brackets .

`fileName="${tempdir}/MyAppLogs/sample.log"`